# Event sourcing: non-business important events

Tags: event-sourcing

This is a general architectural question on ES. The concern is generally about the need to keep a great amount of business non-important events, that affect intermediate state, though we definitely won't care about them (will just ignore them) at the end of the day.

Say we have a User, that has a list of items (i.e Tasks), and the user may quite often add/remove/edit different fields of a task. If we are building ES, we should treat each update as an individual event for example `TaskNameChange`, `TaskCommentChange` etc, or we may have one event `TaskModified` whatever. **In our case tasks state changes are actually not important for us**, is we don't get much from task change history, from the business standpoint we will ever care about only last ones (for example last `TaskNameChange`), but we should anyway track and record all the events.

Again my concern is that we should record and keep a great amount of business meaningless events in event store.

Has anyone met such situation and what are ideas about it?

Comment: What do you mean with `are actually not important`? What do you need to do with those events? Do you need to track a "task name changed" event? If so, you need store that event. If you don't, just dont store it.

Comment: The event actually changes the state, next event will change it again, previous events will be non-important.

Comment: I understand. So, I guess you have to study how complex is to change the state from a "big" event (TaskChanged) vs a "simpler" one (e.g. TaskNameChanged). I guess the first one is overwrite the whole "entity" and the second one just modify it. It's up to you now.

Comment: But actually, granularity here doesn't really matter, either will have multiple granular events or multiple non-granular TaskChanged events, because they happen at a different time.

Comment: Don't post your questions on multiple sites.  Decide which site you want your question to live on, and delete it from the others.

Comment: " from the business standpoint we will ever care about only last ones (for example last TaskNameChange), but we should anyway track and record all the events." - I don't get it. Why `buy` something if you don't need it?

Comment: Because this event is need to actualize state, but as soon as new event of this type arrives previous may (will) loose actual business value - we will never need them, but still have to keep them, and there maybe a lof of those events, actually useless in a long run.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR but why do you have to keep  it if you don't need it?

Comment: To be ES consistent. See my comment to the answer given by @VoiceOfUnreason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone met such situation and what are ideas about it?

*Horses for courses*

If the costs associated with keeping a complete event backed history of your document exceed the business value that you can accrue from that history, then don't design your system to keep all of the history.  Set up a document store, on each save overwrite the previous version of the document, and get on with it.

Greg Young: [a whole system based on event sourcing is an anti pattern](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/04/event-sourcing-anti-pattern).

Comment: I get your point thanks. So do you think it is ok to have for example `add` and `remove` events for items in ES system, but keep a current state of items (that will be effected by change events or better to say commands) in a separate place and not store change events themselfs? This complicates system thouh.

Comment: So I believe you are correct will mark as the asnwer.